# Is it somehow possible to dynamically calculate the X percent of RDS/Elasticache nodes available memory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

I'm currently working on creating Cloudwatch alarms for RDS/Elasticache based on available metrics using CloudFormation in combination with Ansible. However, I've encountered an issue with the "FreeableMemory" metric for these services. Specifically, I want to create an alarm when only 10% of free memory remains on the node, and the threshold for this metric needs to be provided in bytes. Currently, I'm using a fixed value of 100MB as the threshold, but this may not be appropriate for all node types since they can vary in memory capacity (e.g., cache.t3.micro and db.t3.micro have 1GB memory available while other node types may have different values).

To solve this problem, I have attempted to retrieve the memory value of the node type using the AWS CLI, but it seems that this information is not available in the API. I would greatly appreciate any ideas or suggestions on how to handle this issue and set appropriate thresholds for different node types.

Here is the cloudwatch alarm resource example

```
CriticalLaravelRDSRamCloudWatchAlarm:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    ActionsEnabled: true
    AlarmActions:
      - Ref: SNSTopic
    OKActions:
      - Ref: SNSTopic
    AlarmDescription: "RDS RAM utilization alarm"
    AlarmName:
      Fn::Join:
        - " "
        - - "Critical!"
          - Ref: LaravelRDSInstance
          - "Memory utilization is high"
    ComparisonOperator: LessThanOrEqualToThreshold
    Dimensions:
      - Name: DBInstanceIdentifier
        Value:
          Ref: LaravelRDSInstance
    EvaluationPeriods: 1
    MetricName: FreeableMemory
    Namespace: AWS/RDS
    Period: 60
    Statistic: Average
    Threshold: 104857600
```

I need to somehow retrieve the value of memory of the node type in Ansible so I can calculate the percent